# Sometimes loading JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

I'd like to conditionally load a set of javascript functions (which involve jQuery) on a given page.

The situation is that our site has a bunch of stuff that happens on `$(document).ready` (mostly fancy menu setup and a couple of CSS class manipulations), but one or two pages need more setup. It's enough code (and specific enough) that I don't want to just toss it into the main file, but rather just load it on those specific pages.

It seems that I can't do this by just loading a new file `specific.js` into those pages that contains

```
(function () {
   $(something).click(function () { Stuff(happens); });
   something(Else);
   ...
 } ());
```

In the above example, `something(Else);` works fine, but `.click` and `.bind` don't seem to do anything. What I ended up doing is

```
function specificStuff () {
   $(something).click(function () { Stuff(happens); });
   something(Else);
   ...
};
```

and adding `if(specificStuff) specificStuff();` to the main js file. It works, but it seems like there should be a better way of accomplishing this (ideally one that would keep all the changes in `specific.js` and not touch the general settings).

Is there a canonical way of conditionally loading js code to run in `document.ready`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `$(document).ready();` multiple times in a web page/script file.  Just wrap your jquery bindings as such in your `specific.js` file:

`$(document).ready(function(){
   $(something).click(function () { Stuff(happens); }); 
   something(Else);});`

Comment: Wow. I was severely overthinking this.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the page specific Javascript in the html of those pages, each script with its own document.ready function.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the () when passing a function to document.ready:

```
(function () {
   $(something).click(function () { Stuff(happens); });
   something(Else);
   ...
 } **()**);
```

with the (), it will execute **right away** and not wait for the document to be ready.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the jquery document ready function as many times as you need. I think your issue is with how you've set up your function. If you're trying to call the ready function, it should be like this:

```
$(function () {
   $(something).click(function () { Stuff(happens); });
   something(Else);
   ...
});
```

Also, if the `something` elements are created by your main.js file, you should include it *before* your specific.js file.